# Tensorflow: does feeding a value to a variable override its value permanently?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a NN model with some weights, and I need to be able to make inference (and learning) using sometiems a set of weights A and sometimes a set of weights B.
I know I can feed values to Variables and not only to placeholders, but if I do so I permanently override the variable value or is it temporary, within the execution window of the op nodes requested?

For example,
Let's assume I built the graph and learnt a model using weight set A.
If I want to make inference using another weight set, set B, I can do:

```
sess.run(output, feed_dict={input:input, weights:weightsB}) #inference
```

**My question is:** If I feed the values weightsB, will they permanently override the values of the network? If next time I will run

```
sess.run(output, feed_dict={input:input}) #inference
```

will it use weightsA or weightsB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In TensorFlow, feeding a value for a variable in one step **does not** affect the value stored in that variable. In subsequent steps, if you use the variable, it will continue to have its previous value.

Note that if you want a feed to change the value of a variable in future steps, you should explicitly **assign** that value to the variable, using a construction like:

```
v = tf.Variable(...)
v_update_placeholder = tf.placeholder(v.dtype, shape=v.shape)
v_update_op = v.assign(v_update_placeholder).op

# ...

sess.run(v_update_op, feed_dict={v_update_placeholder: ...})
```