# Assigning a runtime value to a tensorflow variable

Tags: python, tensorflow

I feel like in similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34220532/how-to-assign-value-to-a-tensorflow-variable) none of the answers answer my question.

Firstly: Do I **have** to create an assign operation to assign a new value to a tensorflow variable? I saw an example where `feed_dict` is used, but is that assignment actually permanent (usually `feed_dict` is used to placeholders a value and I would assume after `run` is executed those variables do not keep that value that was fed)? EDIT: It is not permanent.
Secondly it seems like with `assign`, you have to know the value at compile time?

What I really want to do is assign multiple numpy arrays to my weights at runtime. How can I do that?

This answers the question: [Tensorflow: does feeding a value to a variable override its value permanently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43128436/tensorflow-does-feeding-a-value-to-a-variable-override-its-value-permanently)

Comment: `feed_dict` is used only for placeholders. Variables can only be initialized, used in tf operations and `assign`ed

Comment: Really? Answer here says otherwise: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34220532/how-to-assign-value-to-a-tensorflow-variable

Comment: well, my bad, Salvador always right (:

Comment: So I just tested it and the change is not permanent.

Comment: what do you mean by permanent? not trainable weights?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, **yes**, you have to use the `assign` operator to change a `Variable`'s value. My tests with `feed_dict` agree with your results - the update doesn't do anything.